# Re-render ReactJS nested child components based on data passed by location.hash

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is this the good approach to rerender nested components based on location.hash? I wonder if it is a good approach to re-render the entire main components just to update a very nested child component.

http://jsfiddle.net/fL99kh4x/1/

```js
var router = (function () {

    ...

}());


var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <a href = "#d/test" > Hello {
            this.props.name
        } < /a>;
    }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <Hello name={this.props.name} / > ;
    }
});

router.addRoute('', function () {
    React.render( < Main name = "World" / > , document.body);
});

router.addRoute('d/:id', function (id) {
    React.render( < Main name = "Earth" / > , document.body);
});

router.start();
```

I don't want just handle the click event so that the view is correct even if the page is called directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; in fact, many (most?) React-specific routers work like this. Remember, "re-rendering" in React doesn't mean blowing away the entire DOM, it just means calculating a new *virtual* DOM and determining what to change in the real DOM.